# Masonry Hide Images until fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to hide my Masonry images until the page finished loading as currently the images load in a long strip to the left of the screen, before organising themselves.

I cannot seem to get the container to hide and then show once everything else has been loaded.

Here is the link: http://inspiredworx-labs.com/sites/blg/

Here is my snippet (with commented out code that I've tried to implement for the hide/show bit):

```
        <script>
    $(window).load( function(){   
            var $container = $('#masonry-container');
            // initialize
            $container.masonry({
              //columnWidth: 60,
              gutter: 6,
              itemSelector: '.masonry-item'
            });
    })

    /*
            $('#masonry-container').hide();
            $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
                $('#masonry-container').show();
            })          
    */
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include your Masonry instance within your images `imagesLoaded` like so:

```
var $container = $('#masonry-container');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
         itemSelector: '.masonry-item',
         gutter: 6
    });
});
```

Comment: When I add this snippet the images stay on the left in a row. EDIT: I installed the imagesLoaded script and it seems to load faster now? Is there any way of hiding then showing once all images are ready?

Comment: It shouldn't really be faster. Maybe your images were just cached. You could hide all images by default on load but you will still need to call `$container.masonry()` again so that it re-sizes the `.masonry-item` elements correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I do not getting whatever you have tried.

But there is a javascript library that is  "**imagesLoaded**".
that will help you
I did it in this way

```
//  created a array with image and data
 var elemar  = [];
$.each(data, function(j,subData){

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'images.jpg';
    item.appendChild( img );                        
    elemar.push(item);
});

// loading div after image loaded
imagesLoaded(elemar).on( 'progress', function( imgLoad, image ) {
        var item = image.img.parentNode;        
        container.appendChild( item );// container is an javascript , $('#containerdiv'), where all div will be publish
        msnry.appended( item ); // msnry intializaion
        });
});
```

Comment: Why not just call `imagesLoaded` on the containing element?

Comment: Hey i am getting data through ajax, so first i created dom elements then i inserted, b/c i don't want to display text, if images is loading.

Comment: Hmm, interesting way of doing it.